# Disallow slicing to keep multiple parent class properties in sync

Tags: c++

I am deriving an object from two parent classes. These two parents each have different types of properties, but I want the child to keep them in sync with each other. However, I want to disallow users of the library from treating `Child` like a `ParentA` or a `ParentB` accidentally via slicing. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class ParentA
{
public:
    void modify()
    {
        std::cout << "modifyA" << std::endl;
    }

    void readA()
    {
        std::cout << "readA" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ParentB
{
public:
    void modify()
    {
        std::cout << "modifyB" << std::endl;
    }
    void readB()
    {
        std::cout << "readB" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public ParentA, public ParentB
{
public:
    void modify()
    {
        // Do some bounds checking to make sure ParentA and ParentB stay in sync, then:
        ParentA::modify();
        ParentB::modify();
        std::cout << "modifyChild" << std::endl;
    }
};

void Change(ParentA object)
{
    object.modify();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is standard:" << std::endl;
    ParentA parentA;
    parentA.modify();

    ParentB parentB;
    parentB.modify();

    Child child;
    child.readA();
    child.readB();
    child.modify();

    std::cout << "Want to avoid this:" << std::endl;
    Change(child);

    return 0;
}
```

This call to `Change(child);` calls `ParentA`'s `modify()` function, in which the `ParentA` properties can get out of sync with the `ParentB` properties, leaving the `Child` in a bad state.

There are many functions (the `read*()` ones here) in `ParentA` and `ParentB` that I don't want to have to manually forward from `Child`, so I can't derive privately.

Is there a way to make this call to `Change(child)` produce a compiler error (without changing the signature of `Change`)?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just derive privately from `ParentA` and `ParentB`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon There are many functions (the read only ones) in `ParentA` and `ParentB` that I don't want to have to manually forward from `Child`.

Comment: Pretty sure private inheritance is the only answer you're going to get, or at least the cleanest.

Comment: Forwarding is just `public: using ParentA::getterX;`, doing that for a handful of functions shouldn't hurt.

Comment: BTW: What you want here has nothing to do with slicing, even if you completely disabled assignment and copying. The problem is rather that you don't want to disable access to one of the baseclass' public functions. So, your derived class should not support the interface that the baseclass supports, so it is not substitutable according to Liskov and public inheritance is not an option.

Comment: Your change function only takes a reference - so there is no slicing... You could just make `ParentA::modify` and `ParentB::modify` virtual.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Fixed (removed reference in `Change()`).

Comment: Do you need to instantiate objects of `ParentA` and `ParentB`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, they are each fully usable independently - `Child` just needs both sets of functionality (and to keep them in sync).

Comment: Making the baseclass' `modify()` functions virtual doesn't help, @SimonKraemer, because you could still call the baseclass version explicitly even if it was overridden in the derived class. Instead, you would need a public, nonvirtual function calling a private/protected virtual function. I'm not sure if that works with multiple inheritance though. In either case, the change would be as much effort as using private inheritance and forwarding.

Comment: David, with your recent change, nothing goes out of sync either, simply because the `ParentA` subobject of `child` is copied (which is slicing), so the `ParentA` and `ParentB` subobjects remain unchanged. You could simply disable slicing with the well-known methods against that, too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, now it does. When OP was still using a reference it would have helped against accidental uses... Of course only for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a way to do this (although said you didn't like it): `private` or `protected` inheritance is the C++ mechanism to achieve what you want.

Bear in mind that since your child class is trying to keep some sort of invariant between A and B, if you inherit `public`ly, someone will find a way to use A or B's interface to violate the invariant anyway so you need to protect against those being used in the child directly, which the restricted inheritance does perfectly.

If there are then some methods in the parent that don't affect the two-class invariant you can `using` those down into the public section of Child.

Comment: Do you know a way to avoid this `Change(reinterpret_cast<ParentA&>(child));`?

Comment: @Simon Kraemer There's not a lot you can do to protect against misuse of `reinterpret_cast`, but its name makes it really easy for static checkers (or even grep) to find and flag.

Comment: Thought so. But yeah - this is definitely no "accidential" use.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already say the cleanest way might be to just inherit from `ParentA` and `ParentB` with `private` and forward the needed functions.

I had another idea: You could extract the functionality of `ParentA` and `ParentB` into 2 abstract classes (`AbstractParentA`,`AbstractParentB`) and use these classes as base classes.

This would give you the desired behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractParentA
{
    virtual void no_instance() = 0;

public:
    void modify()
    {
        std::cout << "modifyA" << std::endl;
    }

    void readA()
    {
        std::cout << "readA" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AbstractParentB
{
    virtual void no_instance() = 0;

public:
    void modify()
    {
        std::cout << "modifyB" << std::endl;
    }
    void readB()
    {
        std::cout << "readB" << std::endl;
    }
};


class ParentA : public AbstractParentA
{
    virtual void no_instance() override {}
};


class ParentB : public AbstractParentB
{
    virtual void no_instance() override {}
};

class Child : public AbstractParentA, public AbstractParentB
{
    virtual void no_instance() override {}

public:
    void modify()
    {
        // Do some bounds checking to make sure ParentA and ParentB stay in sync, then:
        AbstractParentA::modify();
        AbstractParentB::modify();
        std::cout << "modifyChild" << std::endl;
    }
};

void Change(ParentA object)
{
    object.modify();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is standard:" << std::endl;
    ParentA parentA;
    parentA.modify();

    ParentB parentB;
    parentB.modify();

    Child child;
    child.readA();
    child.readB();
    child.modify();

    std::cout << "Want to avoid this:" << std::endl;
    Change(child);

    return 0;
}
```

> error C2664: 'void Change(ParentA)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Child'
>
> note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called